# Issue with Differential Privacy Epsilon Setting in Gretel's Tabular Model

Tags: python, privacy

"Hello everyone, I'm working on a project that involves creating synthetic data using Gretel.ai's synthetic data generation tools. Specifically, I'm using the 'tabular-differential-privacy' model.

I've encountered a problem when changing the epsilon value in the model configuration. Epsilon is supposed to determine the level of privacy in the output synthetic data: a lower epsilon should result in more privacy, whereas a higher epsilon should reduce privacy and provide a synthetic dataset that is closer to the original one.

However, I've noticed an inconsistency: when I increase the epsilon value, the amount of privacy seems to increase instead of decrease. I'm checking this by monitoring the number of 'canary' entries, artificial entries I've inserted into the dataset which should not be repeated in the synthetic data. As I increase epsilon, the number of canaries in the output decreases, which suggests a higher level of privacy.

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```py
config = read_model_config("synthetics/tabular-differential-privacy")
config["models"][0]["tabular_dp"]["params"]["epsilon"] = 10
model = project.create_model_obj(model_config=config, data_source=data_source_identifier)
model.submit_cloud()
```

Here's the configuration I'm using for the model:

```
{'models': [{'tabular_dp': {'data_source': '__tmp__',
                            'params': {'delta': 'auto',
                                       'epsilon': 10,
                                       'infer_domain': True}}}],
 'name': 'scooter-readmission-tabular-dp-epsilon-10',
 'schema_version': '1.0'}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nx2t.png)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask